# Web browser that can load a large YouTube "Liked videos" page without slowing down

Tags: web-browser, youtube

I have ~4000 liked videos. Can't seem to open that page and reach the bottom without Firefox or Chrome displaying the message "This page is slowing FF/Cr down" and/or crashes. Could you offer some solution?

BTW, if possible, I want something that can load the whole page at once, so I can reach the bottom with a simple "End" keystroke instead of repeating it for like eternity. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a SATA or NVMe SSD for your OS drive?

Comment: Yes, I have a SSD, not sure if it's NVMe or whatever specification these days. But it's at least 5 years old, and the OS drive has ~2GB free space left.

Comment: 2gb of free space on the OS drive is definitively not enough, simple expansion and contraction of the swap file will fill your drive at times.  You probably don't have the faster NVMe standard if you purchased your SSD 5 years ago.  I recommend at least 50gb of free space even if you have to upgrade to a new SSD like the samsung 860 evo series.  If that doesn't help then memory would be my next suggestion, upgrading to 16gb.

Comment: I think 2GB free is after accounting for the swap file. Anyway, I disabled hiberfil.sys, and now have ~8GB free. Looks like it helps, because I can reach the end of the YT page, but only after 2-3 minutes of pressing "End" and wait, rinse & repeat.

Comment: The swap file shrinks and grow automatically, so you could have 8gb now, but 5 minutes from now the swap file could grow and consume all that space.

Comment: `I want something that can load the whole page at once` there is no such thing, the page has the "infinite scroll" design flaw that basically loads the first chunk only, and then loads the next batch after you scroll. That system is specifically designed so you *can't* load the whole thing at once.

Comment: No amount of RAM or storage space will solve this issue.  As Alejandro points out, this is how Google designed that YouTube page.  Your best solution is to write/find a script or browser extension to simulate what you are doing manually.  Searching for "Autopagerize" may be a good start.  Even after you automate the process, it will still be dreadfully slow because... Google.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Edge seems to take very less amounts of RAM. Your process requires more RAM. So, using Edge will help you achieve your goal.

Comment: But my machine has 8GB of RAM and during that operation, I noticed that the memory that the FF tab required rarely reached 1GB, but the CPU usage could peak near 50%. So more of a page's CPU problem than RAM.

Comment: Try clearing cache and try updating your browser. Plus remove unnecessary addons.

Comment: Edge is nothing more than a yet another Chrome clone. Anything Chrome does Edge will do it the same way, provided equivalent engine versions are used.